# weird JS Warning

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

guys any idea if this is related to the latest firefox built? or how can I resolve it?

```
JS Warning
reference to undefined property o.cache[H][E]
http://10.35.0.211/webapps/core/lib/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
Line 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://old.nabble.com/reference-to-undefined-property-jQuery.cache-id--name---for-large--element-td22728116s27240.html) email exchange with Jon Resig (creator of jQuery) this was a bug with jQuery not playing nicely with strict warnings mode in Firefox. Turn this off and it should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Some points that come to mind:

- Are you serving the site as `application/xhtml+xml`? There are sometimes hickups with jQuery.
- It could be, that the jQuery file was not completely transfered. Try to empty the browser cache and retry.
- Try with the not-minified version of jQuery. Same error? Where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Got it... This is a jquery problem.

I started to see the warning after I had ticked 
"Strict Warnings" (performance penalty) in Firebug.

I am guessing it's nothing to really worry about, tough it pisses me of that there's a small warning from my faverite js framework!

Thanks Boldewyn for your help anyways ;)